# R Loop To New Data Frame Summary Weighted

Tags: r, weighted, psych

I have a tall data frame as such:

```
data = data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                  "group"=c(1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2),
                  "type"=c(1,1,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,1),
                  "score1"=c(sample(1:4,10,r=T)),
                  "score2"=c(sample(1:4,10,r=T)),
                  "score3"=c(sample(1:4,10,r=T)),
                  "score4"=c(sample(1:4,10,r=T)),
                  "score5"=c(sample(1:4,10,r=T)),
                  "weight1"=c(173,109,136,189,186,146,173,102,178,174),
                  "weight2"=c(147,187,125,126,120,165,142,129,144,197),
                  "weight3"=c(103,192,102,159,128,179,195,193,135,145),
                  "weight4"=c(114,182,199,101,111,116,198,123,119,181),
                  "weight5"=c(159,125,104,171,166,154,197,124,180,154))

library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

data1 <- reshape(data, direction = "long",
                 varying = list(c(paste0("score",1:5)),c(paste0("weight",1:5))),
                 v.names = c("score","weight"),
                 idvar = "id", timevar = "count", times = c(1:5))
data1 <- data1[order(data1$id), ]
```

And what I want to create is a new data frame like so:

```
want = data.frame("score"=rep(1:4,6),
                  "group"=rep(1:2,12),
                  "type"=rep(1:3,8),
                  "weightedCOUNT"=NA) # how to calculate this? count(data1, score, wt = weight)
```

I am just not sure how to calculate weightedCOUNT which should apply the weights to the score variable so then it gives in column 'weightedCOUNT' a weighted count that is aggregated by score and group and type.

Comment: Can you show the calcuation of weightedCount

Comment: I do not know exactly how to do this but I do think it can be done with this code: count(data1, score, wt = weight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to `melt` (from `data.table` - which can take multiple `measure` `patterns`, and then grouped by 'group', 'type' get the `count`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
melt(setDT(data), measure = patterns('^score', "^weight"), 
   value.name = c("score", "weight")) %>% 
   group_by(group, type) %>%
   count(score, wt = weight)
```

---

If we need to have a `complete` set of combinations

```
library(tidyr)
melt(setDT(data), measure = patterns('^score', "^weight"), 
       value.name = c("score", "weight")) %>%      
   group_by(group, type) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   complete(group, type, score, fill = list(n = 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `weightedCOUNT` is the sum of weights grouped by `score`, `group`, and `type`.

For the sake of completeness, I would like to show how the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56411717/3817004) would look like when implemented in pure base R and pure `data.table` syntax, resp.

#### Base R

The OP was almost there. He has already reshaped `data` from wide to long format for multiple value variables. Only the final aggregation step was missing:

```
data1 <- reshape(data, direction = "long",
                 varying = list(c(paste0("score",1:5)),c(paste0("weight",1:5))),
                 v.names = c("score","weight"),
                 idvar = "id", timevar = "count", times = c(1:5))

result <- aggregate(weight ~ score + group + type, data1, FUN = sum)

result
```

> ```
>    score group type weight
> 1      1     1    1    479
> 2      3     1    1    558
> 3      4     1    1    454
> 4      1     2    1    378
> 5      2     2    1    154
> 6      3     2    1    174
> 7      4     2    1    145
> 8      1     2    2    535
> 9      2     2    2    855
> 10     3     2    2    248
> 11     4     2    2    499
> 12     1     1    3    189
> 13     2     1    3    351
> 14     3     1    3    600
> 15     4     1    3    362
> 16     1     2    3    596
> 17     2     2    3    265
> 18     3     2    3    193
> 19     4     2    3    522
> ```

`result` can be reordered by

```
with(result, result[order(score, group, type), ])
```

> ```
>    score group type weight
> 1      1     1    1    479
> 12     1     1    3    189
> 4      1     2    1    378
> 8      1     2    2    535
> 16     1     2    3    596
> 13     2     1    3    351
> 5      2     2    1    154
> 9      2     2    2    855
> 17     2     2    3    265
> 2      3     1    1    558
> 14     3     1    3    600
> 6      3     2    1    174
> 10     3     2    2    248
> 18     3     2    3    193
> 3      4     1    1    454
> 15     4     1    3    362
> 7      4     2    1    145
> 11     4     2    2    499
> 19     4     2    3    522
> ```

#### `data.table`

As shown by [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56411717/3817004), `melt()` from the `data.table` package can be combined with `dplyr`. Alternatively, we can stay with the `data.table` syntax for aggregation:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("score", "weight") # to save typing
melt(setDT(data), measure = patterns(cols), value.name = cols)[
  , .(weightedCOUNT = sum(weight)), keyby = .(score, group, type)]
```

> ```
>     score group type weightedCOUNT
>  1:     1     1    1           479
>  2:     1     1    3           189
>  3:     1     2    1           378
>  4:     1     2    2           535
>  5:     1     2    3           596
>  6:     2     1    3           351
>  7:     2     2    1           154
>  8:     2     2    2           855
>  9:     2     2    3           265
> 10:     3     1    1           558
> 11:     3     1    3           600
> 12:     3     2    1           174
> 13:     3     2    2           248
> 14:     3     2    3           193
> 15:     4     1    1           454
> 16:     4     1    3           362
> 17:     4     2    1           145
> 18:     4     2    2           499
> 19:     4     2    3           522
> ```

The `keyby` parameter is used for grouping and ordering the output in one step.

Completion of missing combinations of the grouping variables is also possible in `data.table` syntax using the *cross join* function `CJ()`:

```
melt(setDT(data), measure = patterns(cols), value.name = cols)[
  , .(weightedCOUNT = sum(weight)), keyby = .(score, group, type)][
    CJ(score, group, type, unique = TRUE), on = .(score, group, type)][
      is.na(weightedCOUNT), weightedCOUNT := 0][]
```

> ```
>     score group type weightedCOUNT
>  1:     1     1    1           479
>  2:     1     1    2             0
>  3:     1     1    3           189
>  4:     1     2    1           378
>  5:     1     2    2           535
>  6:     1     2    3           596
>  7:     2     1    1             0
>  8:     2     1    2             0
>  9:     2     1    3           351
> 10:     2     2    1           154
> 11:     2     2    2           855
> 12:     2     2    3           265
> 13:     3     1    1           558
> 14:     3     1    2             0
> 15:     3     1    3           600
> 16:     3     2    1           174
> 17:     3     2    2           248
> 18:     3     2    3           193
> 19:     4     1    1           454
> 20:     4     1    2             0
> 21:     4     1    3           362
> 22:     4     2    1           145
> 23:     4     2    2           499
> 24:     4     2    3           522
>     score group type weightedCOUNT
> ```